# My screensaver kicks in afer a few seconds and changeing it in the control panel is not working.

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I have Windows 7 professional. It was working fine until I had to move the PC. I disconnected everything and when I put it back together this started happening. I have had my techs look at it but they cannot see it happening remotely. The remote software halts it for some reason.

Comment: Does it also happen if you set the screensaver to None? If you change it back, does it happen again instantly? If you change to a different screensaver, is that new screensaver being used?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this might be due to improper shutdown of the OS. Please try booting the OS with "Restore OS with last known good configuration" by clicking F8 during boot and check whether the reported issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's no 3rd party software which might be doing this?

Also, try it with the safe mode if your OS supports it. If it doesn't occur in safe mode, its probably a 3rd party software causing this.